# PanTo multiple markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

say I load new markers from an external source, it looks like this:

```
var markersArray = [];

downloadUrl("eventsxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow

          });
          markersArray.push(marker);
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
```

How would I go about gathering the bounds for the markers and then panning them all into view once they're loaded? I did so much searching on google but none of those solutions have worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. create an empty bounds object (a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds))
2. add all your markers to it
3. use it to center and zoom your map

Something like this:

```
var markersArray = [];
// create an empty bounds object
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

downloadUrl("eventsxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

      // add each marker's location to the bounds
      bounds.extend(point);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow

      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
    // center and zoom the map to fit the bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
```

To panTo the center of that bounds, instead of fitBounds, use:

```
map.panTo(bounds.getCenter());
```

Note that that will not change the zoom level of the map.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xdhyv3ae/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
// Sydney, NSW, Australia. 
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: -33.9,
      lng: 151.2
    },
  });
  const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var markersArray = [];
  // create an empty bounds object
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // downloadUrl("eventsxml.php", function(data) {
  // var xml = data.responseXML;
  var xml = parseXml(xmlString);
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

    // add each marker's location to the bounds
    bounds.extend(point);
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon,
      title: name
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  }
  // center and zoom the map to fit the bounds
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  // });
}
// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a venue_type.
const xmlString = '<markers><marker id="Bondi Beach" lat="-33.890542" lng="151.274856" venue_type="beach"/><marker id="Coogee Beach" lat="-33.923036" lng="151.259052" venue_type="beach"/><marker id="Cronulla Beach" lat="-34.028249" lng="151.157507" venue_type="beach"/><marker id="Manly Beach" lat="-33.80010128657071" lng="151.28747820854187" venue_type="beach"/><marker id="Maroubra Beach" lat="-33.950198" lng="151.259302" venue_type="beach"/><marker id="Sydney" lat="-33.8688197" lng="151.2092955" venue_type="town"/><marker id="Wagga Wagga" lat="-35.1081689" lng="147.3598323" venue_type="town"/></markers>';

var customIcons = {
  beach: {
    icon: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
  },
  town: {
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
  }
};

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Complex Marker Icons</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```