# Recenter map with multiple markers

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I display multiple markers on a map. The list of locations is built with PHP:

```
$myData .= '["'.$Name.'", '.$lat.', '.$blon.'],';
```

Then I use JS to plot markers on the map.

```
function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 32.99999999, lng: -95.2222328}
      });                        
      setMarkers(map);
}

var stores = ['.$myData.'];

function setMarkers(map) {

    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
        var store = stores[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: store[1], lng: store[2]},
            map: map,          
            title: restaurant[0]
        });                        
    }
```

}

I need to re-center the map on map load. Should I try to average lat/lon coords from $myData array and replace **center** coords in initMap or is there a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center map and zoom to fit the markers on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002424/center-map-and-zoom-to-fit-the-markers-on-the-screen)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PanTo multiple markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501915/panto-multiple-markers)

Answer (score 0):

In this story: It's better to get average lat/long coordinates from the back-end (or calculate it on a front-end, but before you initialize a GoogleMap), so your map will be loaded in the right place and will not "tremble".

But you still may have a problem with zooming, and there are a few solutions. Most difficult is calculate again, but maybe you can try something of it (and it may make an interesting effect on page loading):

- A. Zoom in from the space. Set smallest zoom and after google.API calculates bounding box — zoom in!
- B. Show preloader screen over the map. In this case, you can calculate average lat/long using google.API too. It's the easiest way, but not so smooth and cool.

Comment: Great, I was leaning that way. Now I need to figure out how to average lat/lon. Perhaps I can do it while building the array via PHP loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it (a small snippet of my code) in jQuery, just pass your map into the function:

```
function (mapInfo) {
var noMarkers = false;

if (!mapInfo.markers || mapInfo.markers.length === 0) {
    noMarkers = true;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: YOUR_DESIRED_HOME_POINT, lng: YOUR_DESIRED_HOME_POINT },
        optimized: false
    });

    mapInfo.markers.push(marker);
}

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Create bounds from markers
    $.each(mapInfo.markers, function (index, item) {
        var latlng = mapInfo.markers[index].getPosition();
        bounds.extend(latlng);
    });

    // Google wants to zoom ALL the way in for only one marker, so if there is only one, we'll back it out a bit
    if (bounds.getNorthEast().equals(bounds.getSouthWest())) {
        var adjustBy = noMarkers ? 20.5 : 0.005;

        var extendNortheast = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat() + adjustBy, bounds.getNorthEast().lng() + adjustBy);
        var extendSouthwest = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat() - adjustBy, bounds.getNorthEast().lng() - adjustBy);

        bounds.extend(extendNortheast);
        bounds.extend(extendSouthwest);
    }

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapInfo.map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
        var zoom = mapInfo.map.getZoom();

        if (zoom > 18) {
            mapInfo.map.setZoom(16);
        }
    });

    mapInfo.map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I think I like this approach to scale the zoom dynamically and re-center. I'm not sure how to implement though. I've tried putting this code into my JS code  below setMarkers(map) function. I also changed first line function (mapInfo) { to the following function mapInfo(map) { and added mapInfo(map); right below setMarkers(map); It didn't work but it also didn't break anything. What am I missing?

Comment: This function lives outside of your map creation. Once you have your "new google.maps.Map" all setup the way you want it, pass that object to the function I noted in my answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick response! I think I'm close but I am still missing something. I moved the function to another place, where I keep all my jQuery code. My map is residing in <div id="map" class="pad10top"></div> What do I need to change?

Comment: Are you creating and setting up your google map in jQuery. If so the JS I posted in my answer and the JS you have that sets up your map should be in the same file. Then once your map is setup call the function to fit your map to your markers.

Comment: No, the map is setup in a separate <script />, like shown above.

Comment: So you would need to pass your map variable (var map) that you create in the initMap function to the function I provided. But do not call my function until after your SetMarkers function is complete.

Comment: function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 32.99999999, lng: -95.2222328}
      });                        
      setMarkers(map); mapInfo(map);
}

Answer (score 0):

1. create an empty bounds object (a google.maps.LatLngBounds)
2. add all your markers to it
3. use it to center and zoom your map

```
function setMarkers(map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
        var store = stores[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: store[1], lng: store[2]},
            map: map,          
            title: restaurant[0]
        });                        
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    }  
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 32.99999999,
      lng: -95.2222328
    }
  });
  setMarkers(map);
}

var stores = [
  ["store 1", 42, -72],
  ["store 2", 41, -74]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
    var store = stores[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: store[1],
        lng: store[2]
      },
      map: map,
      title: store[0]
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I love the simplicity and I see it working in sample, however, when I add these 3 lines of code, my map loads but it displays from continent to continent with stores on both sides of the map...

Comment: Probably your data is bad (missing or invalid coordinates for one or more "stores").

Comment: Checked the data and it was fine, but just in case I tweaked my code not to include partial data, good tip! Still, as soon as I add those bounds prams, I'm back to the global outlook... I wonder if I'm using an API that supports this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.